# How to inspect sibling elements of <canvas> element using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, firebug

Following is a part of an HTML structure holding a `<canvas>` element with two `<div>` elements as siblings:

```
<div id="block_container" style="width: 255px; cursor: pointer;">
    <canvas tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2; -moz-user-select: none; width: 255px; height: 912px; cursor: pointer;" width="318" height="1140" title="Address.csv">Your browser is not capable to show this part of HTML</canvas>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; width: 255px; height: 912px; z-index: 1;">
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; width: 255px; height: 912px; z-index: 1;">
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now within this `<canvas>` element I am unable to inspect any element using Firebug on Firefox. Whenever I hover the elements while inspecting, only the `<canvas>` element gets highlighted.

Can anyone tell how to overcome this problem? Because as long as I am unable to inspect any element, I cannot proceed with the automation in Selenium.

Also, let me know how to handle this with Selenium once the elements can be identified.

Comment: A `<canvas>` is like an image. It doesn't contain any web element, which is why you can't identify any with FireBug.

Comment: You can identify the canvas itself. What do you need to do with it?

Comment: Can you please clarify in your question whether you mean the two `<div>` sibling elements of the `<canvas>` element or the contents of the `<canvas>` element (which cannot be inspected, because they are drawn on it).

Comment: @lauda: With in that <canvas> there is an icon clicking which we can upload a file. Now while I am working on UI directly the left click and file uploading is happening without any such problem. But right click is not responding to inspect the elements .

Comment: @SebastianZartner: They are siblings of <canvas> if I am not wrong. Because they(two div) were not not nested under the <canvas>, rather all three of them were nested under <div id="block_container"....>

Comment: Using selenium IDE if I click on that icon inside that <canvas> I am getting this id---> 'id=UID_Button147754912997926'. This numeric value can change every time but the first part remain constant. Can anyone tell me how to identify this id with selenium? Is there any such parameter 'start with' for an id webelement?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your z-index properties.

`canvas` has a z-index of 2, while `div` has a z-index of 1.

Now look at the definition of z-index:

> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

It seems your issue is that the canvas element is always on top of your divs.